# what is the use and role of texSubImage2D?

Tags: webgl

After a lot of searching, I managed to get the texSubImage2D function to work. Simply what I haven't found is: what is this function for. In the example below I made a nice effect. In short, I know how to make it work but I am still completely unaware of the role of its parameters. And where to find these explanations?

I'm not looking for the syntax,
the example I give shows that I have (it seems to me) understood it well.
https://registry.khronos.org/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.8

What I don't understand at all is the semantics...
Anyway, if someone could answer with examples so that I can understand.

```js
"use strict";

let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

gl.canvas.width = 30;
gl.canvas.height = 30;


let vertex = `
      attribute vec2 a_position;
      attribute vec2 a_texCoord;

      uniform vec2 u_resolution;

      varying vec2 v_texCoord;

      void main() {
        vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;
        vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;
        vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;
        gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
        v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
      }
    `;

let fragment = `
      precision mediump float;
      uniform sampler2D u_image;
      varying vec2 v_texCoord;
      void main() {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);
        gl_FragColor.rgb *= gl_FragColor.a;
      }
    `;

let shader = gl.createProgram();
const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertex);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragment);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
gl.attachShader(shader, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(shader, fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(shader);

let image_RGBA = new Image();

image_RGBA.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAeBAMAAADJHrORAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAYUExURdUAAKPTdgCN09Aq0w4A09PS0dOoXwD//56WZMcAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAA8SURBVCjPYyAIBJEBNr4SAmDnG8MALr4LBODmh4IAPn5aWhp+fjkBPgH9BOwn4H4C/icQfgTCHx9gYAAArEg8b+0tf+EAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
image_RGBA.onload = function() {
  go(image_RGBA);
};

function go(image) {

  let width = image.width;
  let height = image.height;

  let positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(shader, "a_position");
  let texcoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(shader, "a_texCoord");

  let positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
    0, 0,
    width, 0,
    0, height,
    0, height,
    width, 0,
    width, height
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  let texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  let texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

  const canvas2D = document.getElementById('canvas2D');
  canvas2D.width = 30;
  canvas2D.height = 30;
  const ctx = canvas2D.getContext('2d');

  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data;
  var ArrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(imgData.buffer);





  gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    gl.RGBA,
    30,
    30,
    0,
    gl.RGBA,
    gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    ArrayBufferView
  );

  gl.texSubImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    29,
    29,
    gl.RGBA,
    gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    ArrayBufferView
  );


  let resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(shader, "u_resolution");


  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.clearColor(100 / 255, 200 / 255, 150 / 255, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  gl.useProgram(shader);

  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  let size = 2;
  let type = gl.FLOAT;
  let normalize = false;
  let stride = 0;
  let offset = 0;
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
  size = 2;
  type = gl.FLOAT;
  normalize = false;
  stride = 0;
  offset = 0;
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(texcoordLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

  gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
  gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);


  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

}
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

#canvas2D {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas2D"></canvas><canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: [WebGL Specification - Texture objects](https://registry.khronos.org/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.8)

Comment: [Mozilla Developer Network - texSubImage2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texSubImage2D)